# How to set texture filtering mode in spritekit scene editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, scene

I'm writing pixelart game with SpriteKit and I have a problem with setting texture filtering mode in scene editor in xcode.
While I was setting my textures programmatically I used constructions like this:

```
texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
```

for correct pixel display.

But in scene editor I have only one property for texture

[image]

and I dont know how to set SKTextureFilteringMode parameter in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not doable in interface builder. You have to either set it programmatically or subclass SKTexure and make the new property "@IBInspectable" that will set SKTextureFilteringMode.

Comment: @ira_ira Thinking of it now you can even make an extension in order to avoid subclassing.